# how to use wx.Slider with SELRANGE?

Tags: python, slider, wxwidgets

In the docs for `wx.Slider` ([wxPython for py2](http://wxpython.org/onlinedocs.php), [wxPython for py3](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Slider.html), [wxWidgets](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_slider.html)), there is listed a widget control named `wx.SL_SELRANGE`, defined to allow "the user to select a range on the slider (MSW only)". To me, this speaks of a twin-control, two sliders on the same axis in order to define a low/high range.  I can't get it to show two controls.

Basic code to get it started. I'm not even worried yet about methods, events, or whatnot at this point, just to show something.

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # ... sizers and other stuff
        self.myslider = wx.Slider(self.notebook_1_pane_2, wx.ID_ANY, 0, -100, 100, style=wx.SL_SELRANGE)
        # ...
        self.myslider.SetSelection(10, 90)
```

With all of that, the most I've been able to get it to show is a blue line spanning about where I would expect things to be.

[image]

The wxPython docs all talk about it but how is the user supposed to be able to "select a range on the slider", like shown here (taken from [`shiny`](http://shiny.rstudio.com))?

[image]

What am I missing? Are there any reasonable public examples of a wxPython `wx.Slider` in the wild with this functionality?

PS:

- One page I found speaks of WinXP only, but since that page hasn't been updated in seven years, I don't consider it authoritative on the version restriction.
- I've been using wxGlade for gui layout, but I'm certainly willing/able to go into the code after export and muck around.

System: win81_64, python-2.7.10, wxPython-3.0.2.0

Comment: Hi, have you ever figured that out? Have the same problem, and finding nothing on this on the web.

Comment: Nothing found, though I haven't been looking recently. I should check if the package has had relevant updates.

Comment: Not really. I made a custom implementation, which I post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a custom implementation for this, partly using a code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961456/get-wxpython-sliders-value-under-mouse-click/9976957#9976957).  Left click on the slider area sets the left border of the range, right click sets the right border.  Dragging the slider moves the selection.  `left_gap` and `right_gap` indicates what is the empty space between edges of the widget and actual start of the drawn slider. As in the source, these must be found out by experimentation.

```
class RangeSlider(wx.Slider):
def __init__(self, left_gap, right_gap, *args, **kwargs):
    wx.Slider.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.left_gap = left_gap
    self.right_gap = right_gap
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.on_left_click)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_UP, self.on_right_click)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL_PAGEUP, self.on_pageup)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL_PAGEDOWN, self.on_pagedown)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL_THUMBTRACK, self.on_slide)

    self.slider_value=self.Value
    self.is_dragging=False

def linapp(self, x1, x2, y1, y2, x):
    proportion=float(x - x1) / (x2 - x1)
    length = y2 - y1
    return round(proportion*length + y1)

# if left click set the start of selection
def on_left_click(self, e):

    if not self.is_dragging: #if this wasn't a dragging operation
        position = self.get_position(e)
        if position <= self.SelEnd:
            self.SetSelection(position, self.SelEnd)
        else:
            self.SetSelection(self.SelEnd, position)
    else:
        self.is_dragging = False
    e.Skip()

# if right click set the end of selection
def on_right_click(self, e):
    position = self.get_position(e)
    if position >= self.SelStart:
        self.SetSelection(self.SelStart, position)
    else:
        self.SetSelection(position, self.SelStart)
    e.Skip()

# drag the selection along when sliding
def on_slide(self, e):
    self.is_dragging=True
    delta_distance=self.Value-self.slider_value
    self.SetSelection(self.SelStart+delta_distance, self.SelEnd+delta_distance)
    self.slider_value=self.Value

# disable pageup and pagedown using following functions
def on_pageup(self, e):
    self.SetValue(self.Value+self.PageSize)

def on_pagedown(self, e):
    self.SetValue(self.Value-self.PageSize)

# get click position on the slider scale
def get_position(self, e):
    click_min = self.left_gap #standard size 9
    click_max = self.GetSize()[0] - self.right_gap #standard size 55
    click_position = e.GetX()
    result_min = self.GetMin()
    result_max = self.GetMax()
    if click_position > click_min and click_position < click_max:
        result = self.linapp(click_min, click_max,
                             result_min, result_max,
                             click_position)
    elif click_position <= click_min:
        result = result_min
    else:
        result = result_max

    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem before and couldn't find a good solution. What I ended up doing was creating my own custom `RangeSlider` widget with two actual thumbs.
Code is available in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59494283/8378726), or in this [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/gabrieldp/e19611abead7f6617872d33866c568a3).

[image: Range slider demo.]

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never: to answer the original question, `wxSL_SELRANGE` does work but it only results in the expected appearance if it's combined with `wxSL_LABELS`. With both of these styles (and the selection set to 20..80 for the total range 0..100) the control appears like this: [image: screenshot of wxSlider]